# The need of Xilnx AXI BRAM Controller IP

Tags: fpga

Why someone needs to use AXI BRAM Controller IP, when BRAM supports AXI interface?

Details:
Xilnx provides the AXI BRAM Controller IP which allows to connect to BRAM memory 1 or 2. As a input is has AXI or AXI-lite.
So my question when someone needs to use this IP, when original BRAM IP support AXI input interface

Comment: *"when BRAM supports AXI interface"* Where did you get the idea that BRAM has an AXI interface? BRAM has no valid, ready, length, burst or many of the other AXI signals. .

Comment: actually when you generate BRAM ip in xilinx, it allows to select AXI as interface.

Answer (score 2):

The actual BRAM hardware interface does not have an AXI interface, but the IP core enables you to use AXI or AXI lite with BRAM.

Answer (score 0):

In my Vivado 2017.4 there is no BRAM Ip core.
I have Block memory Generator which will be set to available hardware during synthesis.
As a interface it has "BRAM PORT". To connect this you can use VHDL/Verilog/HLS or for example the AXI BRAM Controller.
So the AXI BRAM Controller is just a tested IP core for translating the BRAM PORT interface to AXI compatible which can be accessed.